System.InvalidOperationException shoots when I give attribute xpath to method XPathSelectElement()
I am currently coding to obtain the attributes and elements of an input xml by use of xpaths.
Consider the below method:
public static XElement GetXElement(XElement element, string xpathKey)
{
    try
    {
        if (xPathKeys.TryGetValue(xpathKey, out string xpath))
        {
            return element.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
        }
        else
        {
            //Key or value not found
            LOG.Log.Logfunction?.Invoke((int)EATSLogLevels.Error, $"Key or value not found. Key: {xpathKey}");
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //log error:xpath not found in system DB 
        LOG.Log.Logfunction?.Invoke((int)EATSLogLevels.Error, $"XPath not found in U500SystemDB: {xPathKeys[xpathKey]} " + Ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}

The XElement that is passed to it is of the form
<track id="1" name="A1">
  <trackTopology>...</trackTopology>
  ...
</track>

The xpath that is used in this method is "/track/@name"
I want to Select name = "A1".
But, somehow when I execute it, it throws System.InvalidOperationException

Well, the method is called XPathSelectElement for a reason, it exists as a convenience to allow you to select element nodes (but not other nodes like attribute nodes or comment nodes or text nodes; and in LINQ to XML attributes are not even nodes, I think).

System.InvalidOperationException shoots when I give attribute xpath to method XPathSelectElement()  Which do you think you should do?  (a) Post a question to SO.  (b) Shoot back.  (c) Pass only XPaths that select select an element to XPathSelectElement().  For general XPath evalation, including attribute results, use XPathEvaluate().
